# How to solve a "list index out of range" trying to make a vector adding?

Tags: python-2.7, list, while-loop

I'm trying to make a vector adding of two arrays with the same dimensions, but all that I get is a "list index out of range" error. The code I used is:

```
x = [0, 0, 0]
y = [1, 2, 3]

i = 0
c = []

while (i <= len(x)):
    c.append(a[i] + b[i])
    i = i + 1

print c
```

Can you point me where is te problem? Any help or idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, try to avoid looping over indices when possible. A more pythonic way of doing this is the following list comprehension

```
c = [sum(items) for items in zip(x, y)]
```

list comprehensions allow you to operate on items in an iterable and return a list. `zip` allows you to iterate over multiple iterables at the same time. This is a good pattern to look out for as you keep learning python

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating both the lists for following index values : `[0,1,2,3]`.

As the length of both the lists is 3, iterating it upto index value `3`, won't make any sense because index value begins from `0`.
In the condition for while loop, you should change the condition from `i <= len(x)` to `i < len(x)`.